# android serial port api reading data issue

Tags: android, serial-port

I am trying to read data from an rs232 serial port connection between my terminal client on a windows machine to an android powered device. I am able to comfortably send data through the device to the terminal but when I try to send data from terminal to my android device, I randomly lose some bits. Also I have to type the key twice on my keyboard to send for instance 'a', I'd have to push 'a' on my keyboard twice.

I am using the source code from this link. https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/checkout

Here's the code for receiving data.

```
     @Override
 protected void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size) {
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mReception != null) {
            mReception.append(new String(buffer, 0, size));
            }
        }
    });
```

and the following is the code where onreceived is called from another class.

```
    private class ReadThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            int size;
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
                if (mInputStream == null) return;
                size = mInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (size > 0) {
                    onDataReceived(buffer, size);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me? Currently, I am working on a machine connected to an Android device using an RS232 port. I need to establish communication and send/receive data between them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was connected to the debug port and that is the reason the connection was flawed. I now connected the rs232 port on the android device to the terminal and everything works flawlessly

Comment: Hi @Susheel, I have same problem right now. I use ttyHS4 port. When I send data to port, it works like a charm, but when I try to receive data as byte array, I sometimes get unencoded char from port. I dont know my port is in debug mode. Actually I want to ask you how did you change your port from debug mode to rs232 (or something like that). (Maybe I can be using my port in debug mode)